# Added new bean.xml and get class path resource [Spring-Mail.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist] with root cause

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I have tried to follow the example at: (http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-with-attachment/) to add a Mail Bean to my project, but it doesn't seem to work. The problem I think is that I can't add new beans, it was one year ago I worked on this project, does anyone know what I might have missed?

```
    jun 19, 2014 11:06:52 FM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [restservices] in context with path [/pyramid] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Spring-Mail.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-Mail.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist] with root cause
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-Mail.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at se.kth.pyramidstatus.webservices.rest.StatusController.loadData(StatusController.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in forehand

Edit 1, the bean.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mailMail" class="com.mkyong.common.MailMail">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    <property name="simpleMailMessage" ref="customeMailMessage" />
</bean>

<bean id="customeMailMessage"
    class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">

    <property name="from" value="from@no-spam.com" />
    <property name="to" value="to@no-spam.com" />
    <property name="subject" value="Testing Subject" />
    <property name="text">
    <value>
        <![CDATA[
            Dear %s,
            Mail Content : %s
        ]]>
    </value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Edit 2, code of execution:

```
 ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Mail.xml");

            MailMail mm = (MailMail) context.getBean("mailMail");
            mm.sendMail("Yong Mook Kim", "This is text content");
```

Comment: What's not clear in `FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-Mail.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`?

Comment: It does exist, I have edited the post with the Spring-mail.xml

Comment: show code of class that starts the execution..

Comment: Where is `Spring-mail.xml`? You have only shown `bean.xml`

Comment: Added, It's in the same folder as my other .xml's that work

Comment: in which folder that file reside ? in resources ? or other ? are this class file and xmls are in same directory ?

Comment: You have shown that `bean.xml` contains the `mailMail` bean, but you say that you have `Spring-Mail.xml`. Have you renamed the files or something?

Comment: Its in resources yes. Not they are not in the same directory.

Comment: no , its not bean.xml. THe file name is Spring-Mail.xml

Comment: is there any sub directory in resources ? try classpath or put `/` before xml file name

Comment: What do you mean by classpath? Yeah, it is in a subdirectory, but I have added that in my Spring-Module.xml (  <import resource="dao-beans/**" />)

Comment: write `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/yoursub dir name/Spring-Mail.xml");` hope it will solve it.

Comment: Hmm.. Keep Smiling.. :)

Comment: If problem solved then you can accept the answer so other don't visit your solved question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the xml file path with sub directory of resources :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/mailsend/Spring-Mail.xml"); //here mailsend is dir name I have taken   

MailMail mm = (MailMail) context.getBean("mailMail");
mm.sendMail("Yong Mook Kim", "This is text content");
```