# In Spring all dependencies is added and spring config also done then while running it gives filenotfoundexception

Tags: spring

```
File f = new File("Beans.xml");
    System.out.println("Exist test: " + f.exists());


      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
```

My project structure:

[image]

Comment: can you share error log

Comment: at com.eql.main.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:19)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
 at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
 ... 13 more

Comment: is this useful- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302956/added-new-bean-xml-and-get-class-path-resource-spring-mail-xml-cannot-be-opene

Comment: i already saw this it didn't work..

Comment: Have you made an entry of Beans.xml in your spring-servlet.xml ?

Comment: No, Can u help me that how to make entry in spring-servlet.xml?

Comment: How are you running your application ?

Comment: with java application, in my project no UI or controller only classes and jdbc connectivity is there..

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below solutions -

**1. Solution 1:**

Try using : `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:beans.xml");`

**2. Solution 2:**

Try moving Bean.xml file to `src/main/resources folder`

and access it like this - `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");`

**3. Solution 3:**

In spring-servlet.xml make an entry -
`<import resource="classpath*:Beans.xml" />`